# Android 21-22 Toolbar button turns black

Tags: java, android

My app is working perfectly but I have this problem that my toolbar button colour changes in version 21-22 to black.Here is the example how it looks normal:
[image]

And here is the problematic part on 21-22:
[image]

Here is my Toolbar and my style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>

    </style>

    <style name="CustomToolBarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>

    </style>

    <style name="Toolbar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

The toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/app_bar_top_padding"
    app:theme="@style/CustomToolBarTheme">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="19dp" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I have tried to change the colour with SpannableString but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer,it's in the toolbar just add the theme and the popupTheme like in my code and it will work.And you don't need that style andy more:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/app_bar_top_padding"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorwhatever</item>` in your styles? (It should be in ToolBar text style)

Comment: Could you try with  <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/yourtextcolor</item>

Comment: It's not that, i have answered the question.

Comment: Could you post your new code? I am pretty interested in your answer

Comment: Sorry I did not notice it. Thanks and congratulations

Comment: It's a bit confusing you have to add the dark theme to it

Comment: HAHAHA True!!! I am pretty new in Android Developing. I see you are also starting. How could we get in touch? I would like it

Comment: No I'm not starting I'm developing for like 7 years now but I get stuck at some stupid points.Yea sure email me terminatorarslan@gmail.com

Comment: Oh that was rude. Sorry man... Thanks it'll be a pleasure to talk with a veteran like you

Comment: No it's ok if you have some questions fell free to ask :D

Comment: AHAHAH I will. I better talk to you through email before StackOverflow set our reputation to 0 ;-D

Comment: Yea sure thats why i got banned like 3 times